# Replace only the text content of HTML tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to replace the string of text contained between opening and closing HTML tags.

This is what I've done to date:

```
        $content =
                preg_replace(
                    '/\b' . preg_quote( $text, "/" ) . '\b/i',
                    $replace",
                    $content
                );
```

The tricky part is that I only wish to replace the text not part of HTML-markup, i.e. not the words in `<div class="word">` or `<img src="../test.img" alt="word">` -- only the text contained between HTML opening and closing tags.

How might I achieve that objective?

Comment: Regular expressions are not capable of that, they are the wrong tool. Use a DOM parser and iterate over the elements.

Comment: *That's* why I have this bookmark - I knew there was a reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: No, not a duplicate if you read this question carefully. Yes, regular expressions can do what you seek, but preg_replace() is no longer the right function for this purpose b/c the "\e" param is deprecated.  Here is some demo code until this question is re-opened and I can discuss this answer in more detail: https://3v4l.org/7JTnW#output