# Only replace words outside of HTML-tags

Tags: php, regex, dom, preg-replace

I would like to replace words outside of HTML-tags.

So if I got

```
<a href="test.html" title="Hello">Hello</a>
```

and I want to replace "Hello" with "Bye" I would like to get this result:

```
<a href="test.html" title="Hello">Bye</a>.
```

Well, I learned that I have to use a DOM-parser to achieve that.

So I used https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser and included it.

Now I did

```
$test = $dom->find('text');
```

To get the text of the dom.

Now I can loop through the results:

```
foreach($test as $t) {
    if (strpos($t->innertext,$word)!==false) {
        $t->innertext = preg_replace(
                '/\b' . preg_quote( $word, "/" ) . '\b/i',
                "<a href='$url' target='$target' data-uk-tooltip title='$item->title'>\$0</a>",
                $t->innertext,1
            );
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, if `$item->title` contains $word, the HTML-structure is smashed.

Comment: use DOMDocument

Comment: You already asked this question once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44324332/replace-only-rendered-text-in-html-source

Comment: Yes, and there ppl told me to use a DOM-lib. I did. But it does not solve my problem. New case ;)

Comment: *"Well, I learned that I have to use a DOM-parser to archive that."* ... I can hear the cheers from around the stadium, there's even a Mexican wave! Maybe there *is* hope after all! Maybe the Pony can be stopped! ... On a more serious note: PHP does have 2 perfectly good in-built XML parsers (work with HTML): SimpleXML: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php and DOMDocument : http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php - why not use one of them?

Comment: What do you mean by *smashed*. Can you give an example of expected output and smashed output?

Comment: @CD001: you can't parse an html document (that isn't most of the time xml compliant) with simplexml, so the only way is `DOMDocument`.

Comment: @CD001: Great posting -.-

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte .. hmmm good point, I've been writing XML-well-formed HTML for so long I kinda forgot that it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer: Of course: The expected output would be `<a href="test.html" title="Item">Replaced Item</a>` but it is `<a href="test.html" title="Replaced Item">Replaced Item</a>` which smashes the site, because now the title is replaced, too and so we got `<a href="test.html" title="<a href...">....`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace only "rendered" text in HTML-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44324332/replace-only-rendered-text-in-html-source)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was much confusion. According to [the docs](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), `$dom->find($tag)` returns an array of all tags, but you are looking for a tag called `text` ?

Maybe you should try `$test = $dom->find('a');` instead ?

Also in your code, it is not clear where the variables `$url`, `$target` and `$item` come from :

```
foreach($test as $t) {
    if (strpos($t->innertext,$word)!==false) {
        $t->innertext = preg_replace(
            '/\b' . preg_quote( $word, "/" ) . '\b/i',
            "<a href='$url' target='$target' data-uk-tooltip title='$item->title'>\$0</a>",
            $t->innertext,1
        );
    }
}
```

This should work better:

```
foreach($test as $t) {
    if (strpos($t->innertext,$word)!==false) {
        $t->innertext = preg_replace(
            '/\b' . preg_quote( $word, "/" ) . '\b/i',
            "Replacement",
            $t->innertext,1
        );
    }
}
```